# re-throwing Error in catch state axios to trycatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, try-catch

I try to connect to api using axios, in catch state I try to re-throw the error I got from fetching and I want to let my catch from surrounding trycatch to return custom message from that re-thrown error

and here are my console logs

```
Password is not valid
C:\backend\aplication\Controller\userController.js:20
            throw Error(error.response.data.error.toString());
                  ^

Error: Password is not valid
    at C:\backend\aplication\Controller\userController.js:20:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

there "Password is not valid" is the custom error message I was talking about, so I want it to be re-thrown and catched in my trycatch

and that's my code

```js
const Login = async (req, res) => {
const {email, password} = req.body;
try {
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/name/user/login", {
        email: email,
        password: "passwordsarewqewqd"
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      }, (error) => {
        //here I log my custom message and I want to throw it to trycatch to respond correctly
        console.log(error.response.data.error.toString());
        throw Error(error.response.data.error.toString());
      });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  res.status(400).json({error: error.message});  
}
```

}

btw, why the code snippet sometimes is in color but sometimes is not?

Answer (score 1):

While I was writing this post I realized that I can just pass the error using:

```js
res.status(400).json({
  error: error.response.data.error
});
```

Like so:

```js
const Login = async (req, res) => {
  const {email, password} = req.body;
  try {
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/name/user/login", {
      email: email,
      password: "passwordsarewqewqd"
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    }, (error) => {
      // here I log my custom message and I want to throw it to trycatch to respond correctly
      res.status(400).json({ error: error.response.data.error.toString() });  
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).json({error: error.message});  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Promises need to be `await`ed in try-catch blocks.  When awaiting a promise, if it rejects, the error will be thrown.  If it is not awaited, the error will returned as a rejected promise.

Inside of the `.then` handler, throwing an error is treated like rejecting the promise (source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#parameters)).

It just so happens that, in this code, there is a `.then` which does `throw` an error *and* the promise is not awaited.  Therefore, the error that was thrown inside the handler will be turned into a rejected promise (based on how `.then` works, source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#return_value)).  Since *that* rejected promise is not awaited, it will never be treated like a thrown error, and the try-catch block will not know about it.

**Recommendation**

Avoid mixing try-catch blocks with `.then` handlers.  Either go for try-catch with `async`/`await` or only use promises with `.then` (and potentially `.catch`).